# Java: How to change activation event key for setDefaultButton()?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

Is there a way to change the default activation event key for setDefaultButton()? The default key is **ENTER**.

This is the scenario: *In login window, there's two(2) button, one is for login and the other is exit. Setting login button to setDefaultButton() is a good idea but I would like to have another activation event key which is **ESCAPE** to respond with exit button.*

Thanks!

Comment: you can use keybinding

Comment: Have a look at [**How to Use Key Bindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: It sounds like a JOptionPane might be a good choice for this, since it creates dialogs with bindings for both Enter and Esc.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should do

```
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "exitAction");
panel.getActionMap().put("exitAction", exitAction);

Action exitAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //what ever happen on exit goes here
        }
    };
```